# Why doesn't rm -rf "$somedir/*" work (only when quoted)?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, glob

Why this command works:

```
sudo rm -rf ${server_tomcatHomeDir}temp/*
```

While the same, but with quoted arg, doesn't work:

```
sudo rm -rf "${server_tomcatHomeDir}temp/*"
```

It might be related only to quotes, but why this command works even with quoted args:

```
sudo cp "$HOME/${artifact}" "${server_tomcatHomeDir}/webapps/${webapp}"
```

I can't understand. Can anyone clarify?

I just want to use quotes in the first command to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: "Doesn't work" -- not so; it works perfectly well at deleting a file named `*` inside the given directory. :)

Comment: Put a `/` before `temp`. It won't hurt to have two `/` if `$server_tomcatHomeDir` ends with a `/`, but your code won't work properly if `$server_tomcatHomeDir`  does *not* end with `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` here is a pathname expansion (glob) token, that will match any number of characters (including zero) in filename, and it is **not** expanded when put inside quotes, it is treated literally then.

Do:

```
sudo rm -rf "${server_tomcatHomeDir}"temp/*
```

Note that, it is almost always a good idea to quote your variables, especially when dealing with file names to avoid word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `*` outside of the quotes, so

```
sudo rm -rf "${server_tomcatHomeDir}temp/"*
```